# Laravel Auth multi Tenant User Connection

Tags: laravel-5, multi-tenant

I've created a Laravel 5.2 App with Multiple Databases.
In each database is an user table.

The login is like:
user@account and password.

I have created my own auth method. The auth method works fine, but then i need the connection name for this user in the app/user Class.

The connection name is stored in the user row.

This is my login mehtod:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    //pass through validation rules
    $this->validate($request, ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);

    $usernameatacc = $request->get('username');
    $usernameatacc = explode('@', $usernameatacc);
    $username = $usernameatacc[0];
    $account = $usernameatacc[1];
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $acc_db = DB::table('accounts')->select('account_db')->where('accountname', $account)->first();


    $checkdb = DatabaseConnectorClass::checkDB($acc_db->account_db);
    if($checkdb){
        $test = DatabaseConnectorClass::createTenantConnection($acc_db->account_db);

    }
    DB::reconnect();


    $credentials = [
        'name' => trim($username),
        'password' => trim($password),
        'account_db' => trim($acc_db->account_db)
    ];

    $remember = $request->has('remember');

    //log in the user

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {

        return redirect()->intended('home');
    }

    //show error if invalid data entered
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Login/Pass do not match')->withInput();
}
```

This works, and he find the right user in the right database. Now my problem, how can i pass the $acc_db->account_db to app/user Class?

In the app/user class i created a function:

```
    public function changeConnection($conn){

    DatabaseConnectorClass::createTenantConnection($conn);
    $this->connection = $conn;
}
```

When i do this in app/user :

```
public function __construct()
{


    $this->changeConnection('test_91550_94');
}
```

This work, but i need this dynamically after login...